# Laravel schedule job on cpanel shared hosting not working

Tags: laravel, cron, cpanel

I have implement laravel queues to my application but facing issues with scheduling cron jobs with cPanel in shared hosting .

> The directory structure on shared hosting is:
>
> - Project
> - public_html

project/app/console/kernel.php
There I have updated schedule command.

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')
              ->everyMinute();
}
```

command in cpanel cron

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/shope/public_html/ php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Note: This is working fine on my local machine when schedule command run in terminal.

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

output:

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' queue:work --stop-when-empty > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define project artisan file in cpanel cron command

```
/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I have tried: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/abcuser/project/ artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` but nothing happed.

Comment: Please without space `/usr/local/bin/php /home/abcuser/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks that worked, the space was causing the trouble.